# Warning: "extra ; ignored" by using C macros with ARMCC

Tags: c, armcc

My compiler raises the warning `#381-D: extra ";" ignored` in such a situation:

I have a struct defined, like the following

```
struct example_s
{
  u8_t foo;
  SOME_MACRO(bar);
};
```

The macro `SOME_MACRO(x)` does the following:

```
#if defined(SYSTEM_A)
  #define SOME_MACRO(x) u16_t x##something
#else
  #define SOME_MACRO(x)    /* nothing */
#endif
```

Of course, the warning is correct, when `SYSTEM_A` is not defined. Simply because I have now a `;` within the struct. But does someone know a way to avoid it correctly? I don't want to break the typical C-style by moving the `;` into the macro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an unnamed 0-width bitfield instead:

```
#if defined(SYSTEM_A)
  #define SOME_MACRO(x) u16_t x##something
#else
  #define SOME_MACRO(x)    unsigned :0
#endif
```

Answer (score 4):

One way that is a bit of a kludge but it seems to work with gcc:

```
#if defined(SYSTEM_A)
  #define SOME_MACRO(x) u16_t x##something
#else
  #define SOME_MACRO(x) int x[0]   /* nothing */
#endif
```

With this method you end up with a struct like this:

```
struct example_s
{
  u8_t foo;
  int bar[0];
};
```

which has the correct size (i.e. as size as if `bar` had not been defined at all).

Comment: Please note that this is not valid in ISO C (array size constant "... shall
have a value greater than zero").

Comment: @undur: thanks - I hadn't noticed the question was tagged as C and had wrongly assumed C++ - but it does seem to work with gcc at least when compiled as either C or C++. I'll leave it to the language lawyers and pedants to down-vote as they see fit. ;-)

Comment: The ARMCC raises the error: "The size of an array must be greater than zero"

Comment: @daniel: OK - sorry about that - hopefully one of the other solutions will work for you. I'll leave this answer here even though it doesn't work for ARMCC in case it's of interest to anyone with a similar problem on a different compiler or with C++.

Answer (score 3):

you can also insert an empty anonymous struct :

```
#if defined(SYSTEM_A)
  #define SOME_MACRO(x) u16_t x##something
#else
  #define SOME_MACRO(x)    struct {}
#endif
```

Comment: ARMCC raises the error "Expected a declaration". Unfortunately, also using the statement `struct test {}`